# android studio app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: android, android-studio, out-of-memory

```
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Continously getting this error everytime i try to run the project

Already added

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Also, have added `multidexEnabled true`

in build.gradle and restarted android studio many a times, but still receiving the same error.

Not even able to run the app once.

-------------SOLVED-------------

Previously i had put environment variable in the system named `_JAVA_OPTIONS` with `-Xmx1024M` value and i changed it to `-Xmx2048M` and it solved the issue.

Comment: I had the same problem, and never realised that uncommenting this line in the gradle.properties file fixes it: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Answer (score 2):

If you already setup your gradle to accept MultiDex options, just set the max heap size for DexOptions:

```
dexOptions { 
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Comment: Did you read the question? That was already added. Besides, the solution was already found.

Answer (score 1):

Add **multiDexEnabled true** in **defaultConfig** in build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Comment: have already added multiDexEnabled true...still getting the same error again and again

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Comment: Hi, sree, already implemented MultiDex the same way, only thing i didnt do was put incremental true inside dexOptions which i did and still not working, getting the same error

Comment: Solved the problem, please check the edited version of my post above for the same. Thanx anyways for your help @sree upvoted your answer for taking your precious time out and answering the query